# Populate Treeview with info from sql?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I would like to ask for some advice on the code I have below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Inventory Balance")


def db():
    global conn, mycursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect('MyStock.sql3')
    mycursor = conn.cursor()


def data():`
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ItemCode")
    for row in myscursor:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=row[1:6])

    conn.close()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns = (1,2,3,4,5), height = 20, show = "headings")
tree.pack(side = 'top')

tree.heading(1, text="ItemCode")
tree.heading(2, text="Description")
tree.heading(3, text="Category")
tree.heading(4, text="Unit")
tree.heading(5, text="Quantity")

tree.column(1, width = 100)
tree.column(2, width = 100)
tree.column(3, width = 100)
tree.column(4, width = 100)
tree.column(5, width = 100)

# Inserting Scrollbar
scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
scroll.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

root.mainloop()
```

I will later have to use this as a main screen, add buttons and have a constantly updating treeview showing as stock is used and then updated via another python tkinter script.
My main issue is that it reads the correct column (ItemCode, Description, Category, Unit, Quantity) but the information contained in the database does not display in the treeview.

Please help and do not hesitate to ask for any more information where required.

I edited the script as recommended and still end up with this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UAfA.jpg)

Thank you again

Comment: Why does your code use `info[1], info[2], ...` when inserting data to treeview? Should it be `row[1], row[2], ...` instead?  And why does the index start from 1, but not 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- using `info` when inserting record into treeview.  `row` should be used
- `treeview.insert(...)` expects two positional arguments: `parent` and `index`

So change:

```
info = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in info:
    tree.insert(values=(info[1], info[2], info[3], info[4], info[5]))
```

to:

```
for row in mycursor:
    tree.insert('', 'end', values=row[1:6])
```

Comment: Please find the edited post above to confirm any faults. I added a link to an image to show the output.

Comment: Did you get any error?  Try print out the result to console as well to see whether records are returned actually.

Comment: There is a typo in your updated code: `for row in myscursor:` should be `for row in mycursor:`.  Also your code did not call `db()` and `data()`, so no data will be shown.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it is only on the post and not running the script with the typo. I tried to screenshot the tkinter window with the code to show the update. There is no error code. It only states"Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: Where about should I add the 'call' function? This is my first larger integrated tkinter project, to clarify.

Comment: You should add `db()` and `data()` before `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: @acw1668Works Perfectly! Thank you so much for the help. Now just to resize and run in full screen, but I have those snippets.